# Find x so that $\left(\frac{3}{2}+ \sum_{i=1}^{x} 3^{i}\right)^2$

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, summation

Find $x$ so that  $$\left(\frac{3}{2}+ \sum_{i=1}^{x} 3^{i}\right)^2 = \frac{3^{22}}{4}$$

I've tried with simpler values for $x$ such as $0, 1$ and $2$. But I can't seem to find any pattern I can take advantage of. How do I solve it? Where would I learn how to solve things like these?

Comment: **Hint:** $$ \sum_{i=1}^{x} 3^{i} = \dfrac{3}{2} \left(3^x-1\right)$$

Answer (score 2):

We have that

$$\left(\frac{3}{2}+ \sum_{i=1}^{x} 3^{i}\right)^2 = \frac{3^{22}}{4} \iff \frac{3}{2}+ \sum_{i=1}^{x} 3^{i} = \frac{3^{11}}{2} \iff \sum_{i=1}^{x} 3^{i} = \frac{3^{11}-3}{2}$$

then use that

$$\sum_{i=1}^{x} a^{i}=\frac{a^{x+1}-1}{a-1}-1$$

Answer (score 2):

$\dfrac{3^{22}}{4} = \left(\dfrac{3^{11}}{2}\right)^2$

So we have,

$$\frac{3}{2} + \sum_{i=1}^x 3^{i} = \frac{3^{11}}{2} \Rightarrow \sum_{i=1}^x 3^{i} = \frac{3^{11}-3}{2} \Rightarrow 3\left(\frac{3^\color{red}x-1}{2}\right) =  3\left(\frac{3^\color{red}{10}-1}{2}\right)$$

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively we have $$\frac{3^{22}}{4}=\big(\frac{3^{11}}{2}\big)^{2}$$
$$=\big(\frac{3}{2}+\frac{3^{11}-3}{2}\big)^{2}$$
$$=\big(\frac{3}{2}+\frac{(3-1)(3^{10}+3^{9}+\cdot\cdot\cdot+3)}{3-1}\big)^{2}$$
$$=\big(\frac{3}{2}+(3^{10}+3^{9}+\cdot\cdot\cdot+3)\big)^{2}$$
$$\big(\frac{3}{2}+\sum_{i=1}^{10}3^{i}\big)^2.$$